# Como modificar o texto de um botão pressionando o mesmo?

Tags: python, button, label, kivy

sou bem novo nesse ramo de programação com interfaces gráficas e estou com um projeto com Arduino...

A parte da comunicação está OK, contudo não consigo fazer algo simples como: Mudar tanto a cor quanto o texto do botão ao mesmo tempo.

Se alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço.

**test.py:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.behaviors.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, StringProperty

class Portas(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, portas, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for onoff in portas:
            self.ids.box.add_widget(OnOff(text=onoff))

class Botao(ButtonBehavior, Label):
    btoff = ListProperty([1,0,0,0.4])
    bton = ListProperty([0,1,0,0.4])
    TextButton = StringProperty('Desligado')
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Botao,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.atualizar()

    def atualizar(self, *args):
        self.canvas.before.clear()
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(rgba=self.btoff)
            Rectangle(size=self.size,pos=self.pos)

    def on_pos(self, *args):
        self.atualizar()

    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.atualizar()

    def on_bton(self, *args):
        self.atualizar()

    def on_release(self, *args):
        self.btoff,self.bton = self.bton,self.btoff
        if(self.TextButton == 'Desligado'):
            self.TextButton = 'Ligado'
        else:
            self.TextButton = 'Desligado'
        print(self.TextButton)


class OnOff(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, text='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.label.text = text
```

**test.kv:**

```
<Portas>:
    BoxLayout:
        spacing:2
        id: box
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

<OnOff>:
    size_hint_y:None
    heigth:100
    Label:
        id: label
        font_size:30
    Botao:
        id: button
        size_hint_x:None
        height: 28
        text: 'Desligado'
```

Comment: Vitão, qual linguagem de programação que vc esta´usando?

Comment: Python 3.7 e Kivy

Comment: experimente chamar a função atualizar()